# Checking inequality without actually calculating LHS and RHS

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, exponentiation, integer-programming

How to check whether the following inequality is true or not without actually calculating the values of $x^y $ and $y^x $:

$$ x^y > y^x$$

(x and y are integers)

Comment: I think compute the values for small integers should be sufficient here. Try $1$ and $2$, for example.

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for all $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese x and y are integers.

Comment: Fixed integers, or do you want to verify the truth of the statement for *any* integers $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, for any integers x and y.

Comment: @copper.hat But what about 3 and 4.

Comment: Well, $1^2 = 1 \not > 2 = 2^1$. Why do you need to look any further. In fact, $1^1 \not > 1^1$.

Answer (score 2):

If it were true then $x^y > y^x$ but swapping $x$ and $y$ gives $y^x > x^y$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm having trouble following you here.

Comment: The claim is that the inequality holds for any pair of integers. So it is true for both $(x, y)$ and $(y, x)$ but they lead to contradicting inequalities.

Comment: But it holds for infinite pairs of x and y. For eg, x = 3, y = 4 and x = 3 and y = 1.

Comment: But it doesn't hold for *all* pairs.

Answer (score 0):

$x^y > y^x$ iff $y \ln x > x \ln y$ iff $\frac{\ln x}{x} > \frac{ \ln y} {y} $.

Consider the function $f(t) = \frac{ \ln t}{t} $.

$$ f' = \frac{1 - \ln t}{t^2} \implies f'(t) = 0 \; \; \; \text{iff} \; \; 1 = \ln t $$

Therefore, $\ max f = e $. In other words, $$x^y > y^x  \; \; \; \text{Holds only if } x > y$$ and they both must be less $e$. $e$ is the exponential number. And both $x$ and $y$ must be positive.

And If both $x,y $ are greater than $e$, and $y > x$ then your inequality also holds.

Comment: But for x = 3 and y = 4, x<y. But still 3^4 = 81 and 4^3 = 64. So, in this case, the inequality holds even when x<y.

Comment: Yeah it holds because $3$ and $4$ are greater than $e$

Comment: What about the case when one number is greater than e and the other is not? For eg, 1 and 3? I know you can tell it by looking at the numbers, but I am implementing this in a computer program.